# Avalonia style in Grid?

Tags: avaloniaui, avalonia

Why can I not add this style into `Grid.Resource`

```
<Window xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="800" d:DesignHeight="450"
        x:Class="HelloAva.GreetingWindow"
        Title="HelloAva">
    <Window.Styles>
        <Style Selector="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="30" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Styles>
    <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
        <!-- <Grid.Resources> -->
        <!--     <Style Selector="TextBlock"> -->
        <!--         <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="30"> -->
        <!--         </Setter> -->
        <!--     </Style> -->
        <!-- </Grid.Resources> -->
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Background="LightGray" Text="Something">
        </TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Background="LightGray"
                   Text="FooBar"
                   Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">

        </TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Background="LightGray"
                   Text="FooBar"
                   Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0">

        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to be added to the [`Styles`](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/styling/styles) collection, not to the `Resources`.